# how can I solve the following linear inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

The first equation is $m_1x_1 + m_2x_2 + \cdots + m_{n}x_{n} = K$, and then
$x_1 \geq x_2 \geq x_3 \geq \cdots \geq x_{n-1} \geq x_{n}$. Rather than solving is there any method which can tell me if this is solvable or not.   All the numbers numbers are positive intgers or zero.

Comment: What are the allowable values for the $x_i$ and what range can the $m_i$ and $K$ come from?  If reals, one solution is to have all the $x_i$ the same, in which case it is just $\frac{K}{\sum m_i}$.  If integers, the Chinese Remainder Theorem is your friend.

Comment: @Ross - Thanks. But my understanding is that for Chinese reminder you need to have more than one equality equation. How to handle inequality like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response to comment-does that mean integers is the answer to my question:  But CRT will tell you when it cannot be done.  If all the $m_i$ share a common factor that $K$ does not, there is no solution.  If $m_1$ and $K$ have no common factor, you can pick $x_2$ through $x_n$ arbitrarily (subject to your inequalities), and solve the equation mod $m_1$.  If $x_1<x_2$, decrease $x_2$ through $x_n$ by $m_1$ and increase $x_1$ appropriately and you will have an answer.  If $m_1$ and $K$ do have a common factor, pick all the $x_i, i \gt 1$ to share that factor and it still works.

Comment: Hi Ross. will it be possible to explain with the example. Let's say $5x_{1} + 3x_{2} + x_{3}$ = 12. This is unsolvable.

Comment: That is why I asked what the allowable values are.  If you allow reals, $x_1=12/5, x_2=x_3=0$ is a solution.  If you allow integers, $x_1=3,x_2=1,x_3=-6$ is a solution.  In the positive integers, there is no solution with your ordering constraints.  To put in the ordering constraints, you can define variables $y_i=x_i-x_{i+1}$ up to $y_{n-1}$ and keep $x_n$.  Then all the variables just have to be $\ge 0$ and usual linear programming techniques apply.